# Hive windowing query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a base Hive table with following schema:
[image: This is my base table]

And I want the below output:
[image: This is the desired output]

So basically, grouping on all columns, and calculating the count distinct Encounters in that month and last 3 months (including that month).
For example, for DischargeMonthYear **Jan-2018**, **num_discharges_last_30_days** would be patients discharged in Jan-2018 (3) and **num_discharges_last_90_days** would be patients discharged in Nov-17, Dec-17 and Jan-18. Since there is no data before Jan-18 in this case, both counts would be the same.
Similarly for Mar-18, **num_discharges_last_90_days** should include counts for Jan, Feb and Mar-18 months (3+2+2 = 7).
For Jun-18, since we have no data for Apr and May-18, it should include counts only for Jun-18 and NOT got to the previous group/partition.

I have the below query that gives me the correct total for **num_discharges_last_90_days** till Jun-18 but does not follow the grouping of earlier columns and for Jul-18 it also includes Jun-18 totals which should not be the case since the **region** is different.

If I add a PARTITION BY region (and others) clause for it, **num_discharges_last_90_days** is correct for Jul-18 now, but incorrect for Jun-18 since it includes the Feb and Mar-18 totals.

`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Encounter;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Encounter
(
       Encounter_no int,
       Admit_date date,
       discharge_date date,
       region varchar(50),
       Facilityname varchar(50),
       Payertype varchar(10),
       Payernamme varchar(20),
       patient_type varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Encounter
select 12345, '2018-01-01', '2018-01-05', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12346, '2018-01-02', '2018-01-06', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12347, '2018-01-03', '2018-01-07', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12348, '2018-02-04', '2018-02-08', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12349, '2018-02-05', '2018-02-09', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12350, '2018-03-06', '2018-03-10', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12351, '2018-03-07', '2018-03-11', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12352, '2018-06-08', '2018-06-12', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12353, '2018-06-09', '2018-06-13', 'Midwest', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP' union all
select 12354, '2018-07-10', '2018-07-14', 'NorthEast', 'ABC', 'MCR', 'MCR123', 'IP'
;
--SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(e.discharge_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'MM') AS `Discharge_Month` FROM Encounter e

--Below CTE is used to get all month numbers
WITH R AS
(
    SELECT '01' AS MonthNum
    UNION ALL SELECT '02'
    UNION ALL SELECT '03'
    UNION ALL SELECT '04'
    UNION ALL SELECT '05'
    UNION ALL SELECT '06'
    UNION ALL SELECT '07'
    UNION ALL SELECT '08'
    UNION ALL SELECT '09'
    UNION ALL SELECT '10'
    UNION ALL SELECT '11'
    UNION ALL SELECT '12'
)
SELECT *  FROM
(
    --Perform a left join on CTE with your query to get all months
    SELECT 
    R.MonthNum,
    e.region,
    e.facilityname,
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(e.discharge_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'MMM-yyyy') AS Discharge_Month,
    e.Payertype,
    e.Payernamme,
    e.patient_type,
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(e.region, '') <> ''
        THEN COUNT(1)  
        ELSE 0
    END
    as num_discharges_last_30_days,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(e.region, '') <> '' 
        THEN COUNT(1)  
        ELSE 0
        END
        )
         OVER (ORDER BY R.MonthNum
               ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
               ) as num_discharges_last_90_days
    FROM R
    LEFT JOIN Encounter e
        ON R.MonthNum = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(e.discharge_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'MM')
    GROUP BY 
    R.MonthNum,
    e.region,
    e.facilityname,
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(e.discharge_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'MMM-yyyy'),
    e.Payertype,
    e.Payernamme,
    e.patient_type
) A
WHERE A.region IS NOT NULL
;
```

`

Answer (score 0):

My colleague cracked the question using the below query. It needed a self-join and CASE & WHERE clauses to only count the last 3 months calculation.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT a.region,a.facilityname,a.payertype,a.payernamme,a.patient_type, LAST_DAY(a.discharge_date) AS month_year, COUNT(encounter_no) AS measure_1
    FROM Encounter AS a
    GROUP BY a.region,a.facilityname,a.payertype,a.payernamme,a.patient_type, LAST_DAY(a.discharge_date)
)
-- SELECT * FROM CTE AS a;
SELECT a.region,a.facilityname,a.payertype,a.payernamme,a.patient_type, a.month_year, MAX(a.measure_1) AS measure_1,
    SUM(IF(b.month_year IS NULL, a.measure_1, b.measure_1)) AS measure_2
FROM CTE AS a
    LEFT JOIN CTE AS b
        ON a.region = b.region
        AND a.facilityname = b.facilityname
        AND a.payertype = b.payertype
        AND a.payernamme = b.payernamme
        AND a.patient_type = b.patient_type
WHERE ( b.month_year BETWEEN add_months(a.month_year, -2) AND a.month_year
        OR b.month_year IS NULL)
GROUP BY a.region,a.facilityname,a.payertype,a.payernamme,a.patient_type, a.month_year;
```